# Is Asus Memo Pad 8 limited to 2 users?

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, multi-user

Asus Memo Pad 8 tablet, running KitKat 4.4.2, doesn't allow me to create a third user. 
Is this an undocumented 2 user limit or is there a bug in the Settings app? Is there any workaround?

Comment: "doesn't allow" What actually happens?

Comment: Nothing happens, the "Add user" option is not responding when there's a second user defined. It works normally again when the second user is deleted.

Comment: I used to have that tablet and the maximum number of profiles were two. So if you want to have more than two accounts I would suggest you to root your devices.