# Is Lollipop limited to two users per device?

Tags: multi-user, google-settings

This is very nearly a duplicate of "[Is Asus Memo Pad 8 limited to 2 users?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/88859/is-asus-memo-pad-8-limited-to-2-users)," but I am having the same issue on a Moto G (1st gen).

Is Lollipop limited to two users per device?

When I tap on "+ Add User" nothing happens once I have two users on the device.

Comment: I could confirm this, It's the same on my Moto G2 running Lollipop. Including the owner account you could add an extra New user account and with a Guest account which is there by default. Other than this three(Owner,New user and a Guest)  account I couldn't add another new user and the Add user is unselectable.

Comment: Certainly not limited to two since I once created four users on my OnePlus One.  Install [tag:adb] and post us the output of `adb shell pm get-max-users`. @Lucky, can you also post the output? // Also, see [Device manufacturers may decide upon the maximum number of users.](https://source.android.com/devices/tech/admin/multi-user.html#applying_the_overlay)

Comment: @Firelord Yes, I think the Motorola devices are limited to two users max. As, I ran the adb shell command and it gives me `Maximum supported users: 2`.

Answer (score 0):

It aint limited to 2 users. If you are rooted, you can use the following shell commands to add/remove the number of users in the device.

```
adb shell # 
su
mount -o rw,remount /system
echo fw.max_users=4 >> /system/build.prop #4 denotes the number of users you want to have.
exit
reboot #to apply the changes
```

hope it helps someone

Comment: echo fw.max_users=4, 4 denotes the number of users you want to set